# Only a type can be imported. org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils resolves to a package

Tags: jsp, tomcat, import, jar, apache-stringutils

i'm new to JSP and i ran into the following problem: I had to modify an application to add some functionalities, i decided to use StringUtils to find strings between tags and it worked OK on my development environment with Tomcat 7, nevertheless, when i uploaded it to my hosting environment, with Tomcat 5.5 (i know i should use the same versions in the development environment, but i didn't know which version it was until recently) i get the error mentioned in the title, of course, whenever i call

```
StringUtils.substringBetween(a,b,c)
```

I also get errors, saying that the class cannot be resolved. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

List of imports:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>
<%@ page import="java.security.MessageDigest" %>
<%@ page import="sun.misc.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils" %>
```

I have the commons-lang-2.6.jar as well as a customJar.jar in my WEB-INF/lib directory, there is also an import from customJar.jar, which seems to be OK...

Thank you for your assistance, if i didn't provide enough information, i apologize for it and will provide as soon as i can in order to solve this problem.

Comment: This is highly likely to be a classpath problem or a corrupt jar file.  Can you open commons-lang-2.6.jar (with WinZip) and make sure it's a valid jar and that StringUtils is where it should be?

Comment: Strange exception, is a stacktrace available? Maybe something went wrong with dynamic JSP compilation. Did you delete the old generated JSPs?

Comment: @Jim Thanks for your comment, i opened the jar in my local filesystem with 7zip and it seems to be OK, tried re-uploading and the problem persisted, also tried uncompressing the jar and placing its contents under WEB-INF/classes, but didn't work either

Comment: @home Thanks for your comment, in the cPanel logs i don't see Tomcat errors, so i can't find the stacktrace, and about your second point forgive my ignorance, but, what do you mean by the old generated JSPs?, where are these generated JSPs stored?

Comment: @Chander: where did you see this error message? Was there a stack trace with it?

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing, it seems like all i had to do was to move my files to the public_html root... i don't like the idea, but at least it's working. Thanks to everyone for your kind answers!